# How to include your hostname in the IPython 5 prompt?

Tags: python, ipython

In previous version of IPython it was easy to include your hostname in the prompt, by including the following in your config:

```
c.PromptManager.in_template = '(\H) In [\\#]: '
```

(the `\H` would be substituted with your hostname).

However, the `PromptManager` config has been removed in IPython 5.  I see the following warning when I try to use it:

```
/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:448: UserWarning: As of IPython 5.0 `PromptManager` config will have no effect and has been replaced by TerminalInteractiveShell.prompts_class
  warn('As of IPython 5.0 `PromptManager` config will have no effect'
```

So how do I achieve a similar effect with IPython 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the warning indicates, you should use the new `TerminalInteractiveShell.prompts_class`.  So to include your hostname in your prompt you can drop the following in your config:

```
from IPython.terminal.prompts import Prompts, Token
import socket

class MyPrompt(Prompts):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        hn = socket.gethostname()
        self._in_txt = '({}) In ['.format(hn)
        self._out_txt = '({}) Out['.format(hn)
        super(MyPrompt, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def in_prompt_tokens(self, cli=None):
        return [
            (Token.Prompt, self._in_txt),
            (Token.PromptNum, str(self.shell.execution_count)),
            (Token.Prompt, ']: '),
        ]

    def out_prompt_tokens(self):
        return [
            (Token.OutPrompt, self._out_txt),
            (Token.OutPromptNum, str(self.shell.execution_count)),
            (Token.OutPrompt, ']: '),
        ]
```

Results in the following prompt:

```
(marv) In [1]: 'hello, world'
(marv) Out[1]: 'hello, world'
```

Comment: Docs on customising prompts: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html#custom-prompts

Comment: @Thomas K,
that doc says `ip = get_ipython(); ip.prompts = MyPrompt(ip)` .
Where in `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` should that go  --
or do I have the wrong config file ?

Comment: That's for in a startup file. You can also do it in a config file by setting `c.TerminalInteractiveShell.prompts_class` to the class or a string of the importable name for it.